# How to save converted html as png to specific path automatically when the page is rendered?

Tags: javascript, html, save, html2canvas

I want to save the png of converted html when the page is rendered to a specific path without click on the button to trigger the download.

This is my js to run the function. It is working when click on the button to download the png.

```
<script>
        var element = $("body");
        var getCanvas;
        $("#btn").on('click', function () {
            html2canvas(element, {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    getCanvas = canvas;
                }
            });
            var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");             
            var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
            $("#btn").attr("download", "test.png").attr("href", newData);
        });
</script>
```

But, I want to trigger the download without click on the button and save to the specified path.

How can i define a path for the file to be saved and without needed to click on download button to perform this action?

Comment: I don't believe you can specify where it will be saved on the user's computer for security reasons, but you can try to start the download by using `element.click()`. You'd want to put the image data64 object in the button's href (and make sure the button is actually a link tag).

Comment: @TheMintyMate Possible to save converted html as an image using php to server?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question?